# How do we make a shared pointer point to an object of another shared pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-libraries, shared-ptr

With Normal pointers it's as simple as:

```
int* p = new int;
int* x = new int;
p=x;
```

But with share there are:
swap, reset, and many more

```
std::shared_ptr<int> x = NULL;
std::shared_ptr<int> y = NULL;
```

I know reset is used for "new"

```
x.reset(new int(5));
```

If I want both x and y to point at this new integer 5, do I use reset or swap or = ? I am really confused.

```
y = x;
y.swap(x);
y.reset(x);
```

Can someone explain please?

Thanks.

Comment: std::shared_ptr<int> x,y, z; x = y = z = std::make_shared<Int>();

Answer (score 5):

You should use assignment operator

```
y=x;
```

`std::shared_ptr::reset()` expecting a raw pointer as parameter

`std::shared_ptr::swap()` exchange the ownership of shared_ptrs without changing the `std::shared_ptr::use_cout()` of either.

Comment: So what is swap for??

Comment: @user3395617 edited answer to include the use of swap

Comment: Thank you so much I changed my swaps to = and now everything works! Thanks a ton!

Comment: I can't see an assignment operator for this http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator%3D

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Here I could see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/operator=/

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It is there even in your link, first (1)